# Android Datagram socket for udp send

Tags: java, android

Should I create each Datagram socket to send upd data every time need send data to server? Or just one Datagram socket for all needed sendind action?

Comment: Fast question, what is the purpose of the application you're trying to create?

Comment: app is used to send cmd to a device

Comment: I wonder if I could create many Datagram socket to send data?

Comment: cmd as in commands? Given that this is the case, then you should probably consider not using UDP and consider TCP instead. UDP is not 100% reliable

Comment: yes commands, while we need udp now ;)

Comment: And also note that some mobile service providers block UDP

Comment: block udp? what that mean?

Comment: I've added up an answer for ya. Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to keep sending your commands from within an eternal loop. Example of this might be the following

```
while(true) {
   // Create the Datagram   
   DatagramPacket outToServer = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverAddress, port);
   // Create socket to send
   DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
   // send datagram through the socket
   socket.send(outToServer);
}
```

Again, keep in mind that if you want to ensure packet delivery, maybe UDP is not the right way to go